# OuterRef and Subquery not retrieving data with datetime filter

Tags: django, django-orm

I have a use case where I am trying to calculate the total value of some transactions given amount and historical price, with the following models:

```py
class Transaction(models.Model): 
    ...
    asset = models.ForeignKey('Asset', ...)
    amount = models.FloatField()
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    ...

class Price(models.Model): 
    ...
    asset = models.ForeignKey('Asset', ...)
    price = models.FloatField()
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    ...
```

What I am trying to do, it get all the Transactions, through a query and annotate the historical price through a Subquery :

```py
from django.db.models.expressions import Subquery, OuterRef

price_at_date = Price.objects.filter(
                      date=OuterRef('date'), 
                      asset=OuterRef('asset')).values('price')

transactions = Transaction.objects.filter(...).annotate(hist_price=Subquery(price_at_date))
```

This returns None for `hist_price`. I suspect it has something to do with the fact that the datetimes do not match, (different time but same date). I tried to replace any combination of `date` by `date__date` but this still does not work and returns `None` in `hist_price`.

Any idea how I can get the historical price for the same date (but not time) though the Django ORM / query ?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried `date__year=OuterRef('date').year, date__month=OuterRef('date').month, date__day=OuterRef('date').day`?

Comment: I hadn't but the this yields the following error: ````'OuterRef' object has no attribute 'year'````

Comment: Ah okay. I haven’t used OuterRef before. What about `date__gt=OuterRef('date') - timedelta(days=1),
 date__lt=.OuterRef('date') + timedelta(days=1)`?

Comment: thanks! but that didn't work either. The error was ````ProgrammingError: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression```` looking at the database and running similar queries on Price table alone there is only one value that should be output with the method so not sure what is going on. Maybe OuterRef and Subquery don't work well with dates...

Comment: Hey, have you found a solution for your problem?

Comment: Just started looking into it again and the issue is Subquery does not traslate the raw SQL to a date lookup vs. datetime - so using RawSQL instead of the Subquery works. I will look a bit more into it and post a solution soon!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the next case:

```
from django.db.models.expressions import Subquery, OuterRef
from django.db.models.functions import Cast
from django.db.models import DateField

price_at_date = Price.objects.filter(date__date=OuterRef('date_date'), asset=OuterRef('asset')).values('price')

transactions = Transaction.objects.filter(...).annotate(date_date=Cast('date', DateField())).annotate(hist_price=Subquery(price_at_date))
```

The main idea is to annotate a queryset with a similar DateField (near the DateTimeField) and use it for OuterRef.